# Debugging a swf that crashes the Flash plugin

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, debugging

I have a swf that crashes the Flash plugin on Chrome. It crashes Firefox entirely. I'm trying to debug the swf to figure out what part is causing the crash. The problem is, before I can start using any debugger, the plugin crashes. I don't know of any way to get a backtrace on the crash. Is there some other way I could debug this swf?

Comment: It sounds like the swf is performing a highly questionable process in its constructor.  Maybe it's stuck in an infinite loop, or it's trying to talk to a back-end service that isn't responding properly/at all?  Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: Also, perhaps the swf was published to target a higher version of the Flash Player than the one installed on the target machine?

Comment: Was the SWF generated from Flash/Flex or from a non-Adobe tool?  Does it crash Chrome from an HTML page or from when you just drag it onto the browser?  AS1, AS2, or AS3?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560979/how-to-debug-swf-browser-crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone's curious, I was able to implement a rudimentary `trace()` function by using `ExternalInterface` to throw javascript alerts back to the browser. The swf wouldn't crash as long as an alert box was up, and the info I traced through the alerts were enough to (slowly) debug the swf.

Answer (score 2):

You should report and post this to Adobe, you'll be doing us all a favour, because no flash plugin should ever crash its framework.

Comment: Adobe knew about the issue already, but I needed to get it fixed fast.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the Swf projector instead of a browser plugin. this will probably be
more stable. Also, see if there's a newer version of the debug swf plugin.

Also, try the free flashdevelop IDE. it has a great debugger.

Comment: Cool, I'll check out flashdevelop. The swf used functionality that relied on a browser, which is why I couldn't just debug a swf.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Standalone Flash Debugger and open your swf with that.

Answer (score -1):

you should test your application step by step, using trace and breakpoints... until you find the problematic part !